# Is it not a good practice in mysql database manipulation?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Since the subscriber table auto- inc number will append 1 even though the transaction error occur and the roll back does not help. Then it can not add the information in list_ sub table since the id is not consistent ,so  I use

> alter tableid auto inc =1

to minus the auto inc number and i put it in the catch block without another try- catch.  But  is it common practice? Thankyou

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, FALSE);
$conn->beginTransaction();
try {

    $email = $_POST['Email'];
    $FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
    $LastName = $_POST['LastName'];


    $query="INSERT INTO subscriber (Email,FirstName,LastName,CreateDate) VALUES (?,?,?,CURDATE())";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);


    $stmt->bindParam(1, $email , PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $FirstName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $LastName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $conn->commit();

}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    $conn->rollBack();
    $query="ALTER TABLE subscriber AUTO_INCREMENT = 1";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    die ($e->getMessage()."<a href='addSub.php'>Back</a>");
    }

$conn->beginTransaction();
try {
    $userID = $_SESSION['username'];
    $query="INSERT INTO list_sub (SubID,ListID) VALUES ('',$_SESSION[ListID])";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $conn->commit();

}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    $conn->rollBack();
    die ($e->getMessage()."<a href='addSub.php'>Back</a>");
    }

$conn = null;}
```

Table:Subsciber

```
 1  SubID   int(11)         No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT    Change      Drop   More 
 2  Email   varchar(100)    utf8_general_ci     No  None          Change      Drop   More 
 3  FirstName   varchar(100)    utf8_general_ci     Yes NULL          Change      Drop   More 
 4  LastName    varchar(100)    utf8_general_ci     Yes NULL          Change      Drop   More 
 5  CreateDate  date            No  None          Change      Drop   More 
 6  UpdateDate  date            Yes NULL          Change      Drop   More   Check All / Uncheck All With selected:   Browse  Change  Drop  Primary  Unique  Index
```

Table:list_sub

```
 1  SubID   int(11)         No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT    Change      Drop   More 
 2  ListID  int(11)         No  None          Change      Drop   More
```

Table:list

```
 1  ListID  int(11)         No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT    Change      Drop   More 
 2  ListName    varchar(100)    utf8_general_ci     No  None          Change      Drop   More 
 3  FromName    varchar(100)    utf8_general_ci     No  None          Change      Drop   More 
 4  ReplyTo varchar(100)    utf8_general_ci     No  None          Change      Drop   More 
 5  Subject varchar(100)    utf8_general_ci     No  None          Change      Drop   More 
 6  IsRemindSub tinyint(1)          No  None          Change      Drop   More 
 7  IsRemindUnSub   tinyint(1)          No  None          Change      Drop   More 
 8  CreateDate  date            No  None          Change      Drop   More 
 9  Reminder    varchar(100)    utf8_general_ci     No  None          Change      Drop   More
```

Comment: Because the database doesn't care if the values are sequential, only that they are unique.  Which is why you should too...

Comment: but i can't append other valid record once there is error occur.
table subscriber auto-inc no. +1 ,table list_sub auto-inc no. remind the same

Comment: This is horrendously bad design, it really is. Just drop the auto-increment on the second table. You already know what you want the value to be. You should not be relying on the database to get it right for you.

Comment: Thanks , please have a look in my table structure, the second table is necessary exist because i have to know which subsciber is in which list . And subsciber - list is in many to many relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is bad design to have a meaningful auto-increment field, for reasons such as the one that you describe. It is not always possible to ensure that numbers will be allocated the way you want them to be.

In this case the imperative seems to be that subscriber number 16 (say) is the 16th subscriber. But do the subscriber numbers absolutely have to be contiguous in this way? My concern is that you are adding extra complexity to your code, in order to satisfy this rule. I value simplicity above all else.

Comment: How can i modify ? Actually the id has no meaning for me , it just a forgien key  in list_sub

Comment: See my comment above. Just drop the auto-increment on the second table, and pass in the value assigned when you insert a record into the first one. You can recover this value by calling mysql_insert_id.

Comment: The second table is necessary exist because i have to know which subsciber is in which list . And subsciber - list is in many to many relationship.

Comment: That means, if i want to know which subscriber in list A later, i can look up in second table.

Comment: I said drop the auto-increment constraint, not the whole table.

Comment: Thank you. I mix up two thing before

Comment: but when i delete the record later, i have to delete it in list_sub , since there is no forigen key constraint?

Comment: You can add an RI constraint if you wish, but you can still do that.

Comment: It seems add RI constranint will be more convenient since i can save the effort in coding. Is there any option to add RI constraint in phpmyadmin? is it first i have to define list_sub.listID as index, then? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I guess i understand what you mean. Retain the forigen key constriant , delete the auto -inc in sec table and use insert_id instead. Is that correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8149/discussion-between-philip-sheard-and-user782104)

Answer (score 0):

nah, I don't think this is a good practice at all. It's just an id. It doesn't really give you any data about the object it only makes it easier to search for it.

If you want to keep it sequential just for the sake of keeping it sequential.....it's mostly an aesthetics thing. Don't worry about it. Your code will be much easier to code and read.

If you want some sort of global unique identifier for some reason then maybe you'd want this sort of thing....but even then you don't really need it.

Comment: Thanks , i have to keep it sequential since i can not add record in list_sub after there is insert error. The auto-inc of subscriber is +1
but list_sub do not +1